# Apache remove last forward slash before the "?param=value"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I was trying to do this but I could find answers just for removing the last slash in the URL without the query parameters. Basically what I want to achieve is this

My original url:
    https://example.com/node/?id=10

And I want to transform it into this: https://example.com/node?id=10

Is this possible somehow using mod_rewrite or anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule to remove directory from non-directories without impacting query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if not a directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for the solution - worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can try if this suits your needs:

Content of .htacccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

I have only made a quick test on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it seems to be functioning as desired.